# GCP Pipeline Datafusion Respond code: 302

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-data-fusion

while running a data injection pipeline I get the following error :

java.io.IOException: Failed to send message for program run program_run:default.test-to-gcs.-SNAPSHOT.workflow.DataPipelineWorkflow.3 to https://r-clouddatafusion:443/v3Internal/runtime/namespaces/default/apps/test-to-gcs/versions/-SNAPSHOT/workflows/DataPipelineWorkflow/runs/43-b80f-1-99-0ebf/topics/metrics6 Respond code: 302. Error: unknown error

the data is not recovered successfully

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you're trying to do and where you're getting errors? Is it possible to share a screenshot of the data fusion pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

302 unknown error usually occurs in case the authentication scope of dataproc IAM account is not wide enough.
If you're using Bigquery or any other GCP service, you need to make sure the dataproc cluster is created with wider scope.

[--scope](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataproc/clusters/create#--scopes)